# Using a greater than sign on linux problems

Tags: linux

anyone help what this command does as I do it with a single `>` and it creates a new file when I do `ls > list`, but I can see nothing when I do `ls >> list`

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned, `>` overwrites while `>>` appends.
Now for the query that you have,

You first executed `ls > list`, created a file named list.

Then, you executed `ls >> list`, which appended the result of `ls` command to your existing file. You can see the changes only if you open the file.

**Try the following:**

Remove the existing list file: `rm -f list`

Execute `ls >> list`, this will create the file list.

Execute `ls > list`, this will overwrite the contents of the file list.

**Remember:**

`> and >>` will both create the file if it does not exist.

Consequent executions of `>` on existing file will overwrite the file, while that of `>>` will append the output to the file.

In any case, you will be able to see the change only when you open the file after `> or >>` operation.

Answer (score 0):

`>` is used to redirect the standard output to a file. (`command  > output file`)

If file exist it will replace it. If you want to append, use `>>`instead.

So if you do `ls > file`, then `file` will content the files in your directory (*id est* output of the `ls` command)